# Difference between cover vs 100% auto for background-size in css?

Tags: css

How to differntiate between  `background-size: cover` and  `background-size: 100% auto`

I have tried both, and they seem the same...

So which one should we use and why?

Comment: If you could post a small live example (see comments below), I could have a go at creating an alternative...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is with aspect ratio. When using `cover`, all of the screen will always be filled no matter the ratio. But when using `100% auto`, if the screen is relatively higher than the image itself it will leave an empty space at the bottom (assuming it positioned at the top with `no-repeat`).

[Cover](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOrKNo?editors=010) versus [100% auto](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQpyov?editors=010)

To best see the effect by the way, the pen would need to be viewed on a screen that allows the content window to have at least 300 pixels height (in other cases it would need a resize). Can't seem to locate the full page view anymore with the recently changed layout there...

Comment: In case if I am unable to use `cover`. Because I am using `:50% auto` any way to prevent that empty space.

Comment: I think there are a few workarounds... mainly media queries and JavaScript. Neither are as simple as using `cover` of course. Then there's `image-set` but that seems to be mostly for targeting resolution and lacks deep support. Here's a nice thread describing the options : http://tinyurl.com/qxs6jey.